# Error when trying to enable JWT for Hyperledger composer project

Tags: mongodb, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am currently getting this error: while following this tutorial https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn

When I run `docker logs rest` I get the below error:

```
2018-12-06T11:22:50: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2018-12-06T11:22:50: PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2018-12-06T11:22:50: PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server:0] online
WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
Discovering types from business network definition ...
(node:17) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Connection fails: Error: Card not found: admin@bc612182
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Card not found: admin@bc612182
{ Error: Card not found: admin@bc612182
    at store.get.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/cardstore/walletbackedcardstore.js:74:27)
    at <anonymous>
  cause:
   { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/composer/.composer/cards/admin@bc612182'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at FileSystemWallet.get (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-wallet-filesystem/lib/filesystemwallet.js:145:34)
    at <anonymous>
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/home/composer/.composer/cards/admin@bc612182' } }
2018-12-06T11:22:55: PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2018-12-06T11:22:55: PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2018-12-06T11:22:55: PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server:0] online
WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
Discovering types from business network definition ...
(node:34) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Connection fails: Error: Card not found: admin@bc612182
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Card not found: admin@bc612182
{ Error: Card not found: admin@bc612182
    at store.get.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/cardstore/walletbackedcardstore.js:74:27)
    at <anonymous>
  cause:
   { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/composer/.composer/cards/admin@bc612182'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at FileSystemWallet.get (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-wallet-filesystem/lib/filesystemwallet.js:145:34)
    at <anonymous>
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/home/composer/.composer/cards/admin@bc612182' } }
2018-12-06T11:22:58: PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2018-12-06T11:22:58: PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2018-12-06T11:22:59: PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server:0] online
Smits-MacBook-Pro:bc612182 Smit$ composer card list
```

[Update]: I manage to solve the above issue however I am getting a new error:

```
[2018-12-06 17:17:59] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
[2018-12-06 17:17:59] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
[2018-12-06 17:17:59] PM2 log: App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
Discovering types from business network definition ...
(node:19) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
```

has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do copy the .composer from your home directory into/beside the Dockerfile?

From the log you provided, it look like you did not. carefully look at the steps before building the docker image.

Comment: yes I have added the .composer in to the same directory has Dockerfile.

Comment: Are the new error was those WARNING, DeprecationWarning messages? That's normal. The error should appeared after the line `DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated`.